# Get-ChildItem to Move-Item - path not found

Tags: powershell

I try to move my old logfiles to a yyyy\MM\dd folder structure by

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -Include *.log | 
Move-Item -Dest {"D:\Archive\{0:yyyy\\MM\\dd}\{1}" -f $_.LastWriteTime, $_.Name} -Force
```

but i get a path-not-found error.

**update**

The source path does not seem to be the problem. It looks like using `-Force` on `Move-Item` does not create missing destination directories.

---

**sub question**: Could the same be done without Get-ChildItem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I found the proposed way of moving logs practically interesting, I decided to complete the task:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -Include *.log |
Move-Item -Force -Destination {
    $dir = "C:\Temp\{0:yyyy\\MM\\dd}" -f $_.LastWriteTime
    $null = mkdir $dir -Force
    "$dir\$($_.Name)"
}
```

Comment: I moved my acceptance to this answer, to have on top of the list. Thanks again for your support!

Answer (score 1):

I guess that for a source file “some.log” the destination is supposed to be something like “D:\Archive\2010\04\23\some.log” and the directory “D:\Archive\2010\04\23” actually does not exist. In this case Move-Item fails. Is this the case?

Comment: No, the source directory (.) is an existing folder somewhere the same drive and the source item positivly exists because running the same command with -WhatIf renders the source item FullName correctly.

Comment: I am talking about destination directory D:\Archive\2010\04\23 for a file whith last write time 2010-04-23. Move-Item does not create missed destination directories, it fails.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken using `Move-Item -Force` should create missing destination directories.

Comment: I have just tried with -Force and got the same result. Help
> Get-Help Move-Item -Parameter Force
does not say anything about creation of missed destination directories. I would recommend a test: for a single *.log file try to create the required destination (take it from -WhatIf) and then run the command. If it works then missed destination directory is still the reason.

Comment: I tried as you suggested an moving into the existing directory works. Interestingly enough a german version of Powershell claims that the -force switch will create missing destination directories.