# Powershell script required

Tags: powershell

this is the scenario.

```
p1

 |_f1

 |_f2



p2

  |_f1

  |_f2
```

Can anyone please help me with a powershell script that copies the files shown above from the TFS to a temporary folder ??? where f1,f2,and so on are the subfolders..

Comment: I imagine this question won't get a very warm reception here...people on this site tend to like to see that you've put some effort it to an attempt.  You'll probably have more luck either 1) asking for a good place to start (i.e. a website or book) or 2) doing some googling to get a start and then asking any questions you have along the way on this site.  I could be totally wrong and somebody might help you, but that's just what I've seen in the past.

Comment: I don't even get what they are trying to do here.

Comment: Does anyone have a handy powershell script that gets a set of files from TFS based on a modification date? I'd like to say "give me all the files in this folder (or subfolder) that were modified after X/Y/ZZZZ" and dump those files to a folder other than the folder they would normally go to... I am totally new at scripting and i need some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with either, but in the interest of a least pointing you in the right direction, check out this site. http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2009/03/pstfs-powershell-and-tfs-better-than.html

There are a couple of commands that will give you at least part of what you want. You will still need to do some digging to figure out the time stamp stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check [the answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698574/get-childitem-to-move-item-path-not-found) on a very similar scenario.

You will find answer to

`give me all files in this folder (or subfolder)`

as well as

`that where modified after x/y/zzzz`

but I'm still not sure about the

`dump those files to folder other than they would normally go to`

---

**update**

Incorporating your approach

```
Get-TfsItemProperty $/MyFirstTFSProj -r -server xyzc011b | 
Where {$_.CheckinDate -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | 
Copy-Item -Destination C:\SomeDir -Whatif
```

you normally can omit the **Copy-Item** -Path param because it will be provided by the pipeline.

I don't have a TFS at to test with *Get-TfsItemProperty* but you could try

```
Get-TfsItemProperty $/MyFirstTFSProj -r -server xyzc011b | 
Where {$_.CheckinDate -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | 
Get-Member
```

do find out about where this $null value is coming from.

I assume you did already see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528806/get-a-set-of-files-that-have-been-modified-after-a-certain-date). To maintain the folder structure on the destination you need to include the **-Force** switch on the Copy-Item to create missing target folders:

```
Get-TfsItemProperty $/MyFirstTFSProj -r -server xyzc011b | 
Where {$_.CheckinDate -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | 
Copy-Item -Destination C:\SomeDir -Force -Whatif
```

I'm still not sure if you need to retrieve/export the files prior to copy them - you should check on the second answer from Richard Berg in the post mentiond above.

Comment: Get-TfsItemProperty $/MyFirstTFSProj -r -server xyzc011b| Where {$_.CheckinDate -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} |  
    Copy-Item -Path $_.LocalItem -Destination C:\SomeDir -Whatif

Comment: but the above code is showing an error as..... Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. At line:2 char:20 + Copy-Item -Path <<<< $_.LocalItem -Destination C:\SomeDir -Whatif